# Ocean Modifer >>Foam Loop?

Tags: loop, ocean-simulation

Can someone please point me in the direction of properly looping the foam for the ocean modifier. I have searched the web high and low and no one seems to know, lots of tutorials mention adding the foam but nothing to make sure it loops with the rest of the ocean. Is this even possible? Because I see this question asked as early as 3 yrs ago and late as 10 and yet no one seems to have an answer or even replies. I have tried to set key frames to quote fade in and out but it never ever matches up. The foam in the first frame never matches up the last in either modifier. Even key framing 0.00 coverage for the first and last frames gives a different result wth...can someone please help? This is driving me mad.